# About performing SHA-256 hashing on the public key

Tags: hash, public-key, encoding

I am following [this link](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_version_1_Bitcoin_addresses), trying to perform SHA-256 on a given public key. 
However, I cannot get the expected result. 
 
I am using the sha256 library in python **hashlib**

The input is

```
0450863AD64A87AE8A2FE83C1AF1A8403CB53F53E486D8511DAD8A04887E5B23522CD470243453A299FA9E77237716103ABC11A1DF38855ED6F2EE187E9C582BA6
```

Mine output is

```
32511e82d56dcea68eb774094e25bab0f8bdd9bc1eca1ceeda38c7a43aceddce
```

The expected output on bitcoin.it is

```
600FFE422B4E00731A59557A5CCA46CC183944191006324A447BDB2D98D4B408
```

Do I miss anything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The result you are getting (`3251...`)
is the result of sha256 on the *string* `0450...`.

The expected output on bitcoin.it is the result of sha256 on the *bytes* that are currently hex-encoded. **To resolve this, hex-decode before hashing your input.** [In Python 2:](http://ideone.com/uFKgAI)

> ```
> import hashlib
> in_data = "0450863AD64A87AE8A2FE83C1AF1A8403CB53F53E486D8511DAD8A04887E5B23522CD470243453A299FA9E77237716103ABC11A1DF38855ED6F2EE187E9C582BA6".decode('hex')
> my_sha = hashlib.sha256()
> my_sha.update(in_data)
> output = my_sha.digest().encode('hex')
> ```

That should retain `output` with the expected value.

Comment: Yep, that's tripped me up too. You'll need to use bytes objects - `b"hexData"` - for Python 3.x

Comment: Good point. I'm not sure how to write the code so it's compatible with Python 3 ("string".encode('hex') is replaced), so unless you do I'll just specify Python 2 here.

Comment: `import codecs`, then `codecs.encode(codecs.decode("abcdef".encode("utf-8"), "hex")[::-1], "hex").decode()`... It's quite counterintuitive IMO, as I'm so used to Python 2.7